# Graphical tooltips in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualization

Is it possible to display a graphical tooltip in R? I have created a chart using plotly, and show, for instance, the asset allocation on the efficient frontier as a tooltip. I would like that info to be shown as a pie chart.

Efficient Frontier Example

[image]

At the moment, the asset allocation is displayed in a text tooltip. However, I would like to display the breakdown of asset allocation in a pie chart. This is the example code ([copied from this useful site](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/333559_274650a583524ac1b086f79a7133fc28.html#)).

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

# Get data
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "NVDA", "IBM", "AAPL", "AMZN"),from = " 2015-01-01",src = 'yahoo')

# Assign to dataframe
# Get adjusted prices
prices.data <- merge.zoo(MSFT[,6], NVDA[,6], IBM[,6], AAPL[,6], AMZN[,6])

# Calculate returns
returns.data <- sapply(prices.data, CalculateReturns)

returns.data <- na.omit(returns.data)

# Set names
colnames(returns.data) <- c("MSFT", "NVDA", "IBM", "AAPL", "AMZN")

meanReturns <- colMeans(returns.data)
covMat <- cov(returns.data)

p <- portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(returns.data))
p <- add.constraint(p, type = "box", min = 0.05, max = 0.8)
p <- add.constraint(portfolio = p, type = "full_investment")
randomport<- random_portfolios(p, permutations = 50000, rp_method = "sample")

p <- add.constraint(portfolio = p, type = "full_investment")
p <- add.constraint(p, type="long_only")
# Get minimum variance portfolio
minvar.port <- add.objective(p, type = "risk", name = "var")

# Optimize
minvar.opt <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, minvar.port, optimize_method = "random", 
                                 rp = randomport)

# Generate maximum return portfolio
maxret.port <- add.objective(p, type = "return", name = "mean")

# Optimize
maxret.opt <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, maxret.port, optimize_method = "random", 
                                 rp = randomport)

minret <- min(meanReturns)
maxret <- max(meanReturns)
vec <- seq(minret, maxret, length.out = 100)

eff.frontier <- data.frame(Risk =vector("numeric", length(vec)) ,
                           Return = vector("numeric", length(vec)))

frontier.weights <- mat.or.vec(nr = length(vec), nc = ncol(returns.data))

colnames(frontier.weights) <- colnames(returns.data)

for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  
  # Creates a new portfolio object using p and adds mean as a constraint
  
  p <- add.constraint(p, type = "return", name = "mean", return_target = vec[i])
  
  # Creates a new portfolio object using p and adds var as an objective, i.e. minimizes var to obtain return target
  
  p <- add.objective(p, type = "risk", name = "var")
  
  eff.opt <- optimize.portfolio(returns.data, p, optimize_method = "ROI")
  
  eff.frontier$Risk[i] <- sqrt(t(eff.opt$weights) %*% covMat %*% eff.opt$weights)
  
  eff.frontier$Return[i] <- eff.opt$weights %*% meanReturns
  
  frontier.weights[i,] = eff.opt$weights
  
}

eff.frontier$Sharperatio <- eff.frontier$Return / eff.frontier$Risk

all.efficient<-as.data.frame(cbind(eff.frontier,frontier.weights))

p<-ggplot(NULL, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(data=all.efficient, aes(x=Risk, y = Return, label=percent(MSFT,0.01), label2=percent(NVDA,0.01), label3=percent(IBM,0.01), label4=percent(AAPL,0.01),label5=percent(AMZN,0.01)),color='red') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  ggtitle("Efficient frontier") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Check out `plotly` for R, which provides interactivity to plots.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as I said in the first sentence, I HAVE created the plot with plotly... As it is, the tooltip is interactive, but I would like the tooltip to be graphical, as indicated in the title of my question.

Comment: When you say graphical, do you mean you want a textbox instead of a popup? When you mention `pie chart`, are you saying you want a pie chart to replace your graph, be added to your graph, or be placed inside the tooltip? All of these things can be done. Could you provide a mockup of what you _want_ it to look like? Or perhaps explain what you mean by 'graphical'?